# Webpack file loader giving me 2 outputs of the same svg

Tags: javascript, webpack

So I tried to setup webpack to work with assets, and I have this icloud svg. What I want is that webpack puts this svg in `dist/assets/name.svg`. The actual output however is a additional name.svg just in the dist folder. So I have `dist/assets/name.svg` and `dist/name.svg`. In the index.html file its referencing `dist/name.svg`. However this doesnt work and I dont know why its exporting the additional name.svg to the dist folder. You can take a look here: [My Webpack setup](https://github.com/Ariiio/webpack)

Comment: You are using html-loader, which by default imports referenced sources. 
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#sources

Comment: If I disable it like this, I dont get any output for my svg:

`{
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                    // Disables attributes processing
                    sources: false,
                },
            },`